# Install Shield Limited Edition in visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

First of all I'm new to visual studio. I need to develop a Setup (.exe) using Visual Studio C#. In order to create a setup, we need Windows Installer wizard. While searching on google I got a link from msdn [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx)

I tried to create a new project as described, but I wasn't able to find "Other Project Types". I searched google again and finally I got: InstallShield Limited Edition template provided by flexerasoftware.com. I registered and downloaded InstallShield 2013 Express Edition, and installed it. Restarted the machine and opened Visual Studio 2013, still I couldn't find other project type templates.

Everyone simply says choose setupwizard under "other project types", but no one provides any description on templates setup.

What am I missing here, and why this much complexity to create setup file wizard. Guide me If I am missing anything, I'm in a serious trouble.

Note : Currently am using Visual Studio 2013 Express edition.

Thanks.

Comment: Express does not support extensions.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Do we have any work around to create installer?

Comment: For me, the problem is that InstallShield LE is not available in the free Visual Studio Community edition ["InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio supports Visual Studio Professional, Premium and Ultimate editions"](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio). There are [free alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/installshield/?license=free). E.g. [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

This link explain where to find it: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx

From the link below: 
>

- To enable InstallShield Limited Edition On the menu bar, choose File,
  New, Project.
- In the New Project dialog box, expand the Other Project
  Types node, and then choose the Setup and Deployment node.
- In the template list, choose Enable InstallShield Limited Edition, and then
  choose the OK button.
- In the browser window that opens, read the
  instructions, and then choose the Go to the download web site link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

This ist you answer:

> Instructions for installing and activating InstallShield Limited Edition
>   for Visual Studio  InstallShield Limited Edition can be integrated
>   into the following editions of Visual Studio: Professional, Premium,
>   and Ultimate. **Note that Visual Studio Express Edition does not support
>   integration with InstallShield Limited Edition.**

I try to see if it is possible anyway...

Answer (score 1):

This link explain where to find it:-https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step-with-visual-studio-2012/

InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio InstallShield Limited Edition can be integrated into all edition