# setup InstallShield Limited Edition 2013 in win8.1

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installshield

I setup InstallShield Limited Edition 2013 for VisualStudio2013 in win8.1. The setup packet is  download from http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio. And the progress of setup is correctly.But when the setup is finished,I can't find InstallShield in VS's new project(just has Add-in InstallShield Limited Edition). I've tried it in win7/win8, it's works,but win8.1 it's may have something wrong. Anyone can help me? thx

I've searched some answers,but there are all unuseful:
[InstallShield LE is not working in vs2013 in windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026651/installshield-le-is-not-working-in-vs2013-in-windows-8-1)
[Install Shield Limited Edition in visual Studio 2013 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809630/install-shield-limited-edition-in-visual-studio-2013-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve this question.My system is win8.1 enterprise 64bit,I'm not sure this problem is caused by system or VS or both of them. In the end, I changed my system to win8.1 pro 64bit and everything is correct. And I've try to setup win8.1 enterprise 64bit in VisualMachine, the problem persists. So I guess it's error in win8.1 enterprise. just guess. I have no time to find a solution in win8.1 enterprise , so setup win8.1 pro instead.

Answer (score 0):

Right click
Troubleshoot compability 
and done!

Comment: Right click the setup packet?